# Returning the "news" top sites to Safari bookmark bar

Tags: safari

I deleted the "news" top sites tab from my bookmark bar--it was there when I opened up Safari for the 1st time, on my new Mac.  How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Bookmarks -> Tick the box for "Include Top Sites" in the Bookmarks Bar, and voilà !

Comment: It shows the sites I visited recently; I want to get back the "news" sites that were defaulted on the tool bar when I opened it up for the 1st time.....

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood !

Doesn't seem you can get them back directly.

They are stored in `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/BuiltInBookmarks.plist`

You could simply import those bookmarks.